# The likelihood of contracting a disease from flies?

Tags: bacteria, disease-transmission, parasites

Given a housefly has landed on your food, and that you then consume it, what is the likelihood of contracting some malady directly attributable to the fly?

I'm aware that [flies can carry diseases such as E. coli](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6104014/) and have even been [used as a form of biological warfare](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-ento-120710-100618), but I'm unaware of any studies showing how likely it is that your average city-dwelling housefly landing on your food will deposit active microbes or parasites, and whether a single fly can carry enough toxic bacteria to affect a healthy adult / child, as all the studies I've seen seem to study disease communication by swarms.

(Note that I'm mostly interested in the Housefly, but if there's studies and conclusions available for other species that would be welcome too)

Comment: This is an interesting question but it lacks the supporting references we require here. Can you link to an example of the studies you mention such as flies being used as a biological attack and disease transmission by swarms?

Comment: Indeed interesting to quantify. But also quite broad (type of fly, environment, locality on the globe…). Please take the [tour] and read the [help] & [ask]. We require prior research information when asking questions. See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784). Please  [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a city or small region (like a state in the US) by your choice?

Comment: @Jan Thanks for your comment. I'm staring at a complete dearth of data; I have absolutely no preference whether it's single flies found in a Brazillian Favella or single flies found in a field in a suburb of France!

Comment: Even though you say you have no preference on the species of fly, the species can affect the likelihood immensely. If you look at the [tsetse fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsetse_fly) or the [tumbu fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordylobia_anthropophaga), they are very different to the common [house fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housefly) or the [horse fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse-fly).

Comment: @ChrisRogers I did edit it yesterday to mention housefly in particular - have made that more clear

Comment: I think the question is adequately focused and researched with the last edit. I'm pretty sure the "housefly" exists worldwide and whatever differences exist between species aren't enough to require more from OP.